# Generalised algorithm to find generating function for any linear recurrance relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

**Problem:**

Formally speaking lets say we have,

$ F_n = a_{k}F_{n-1} + a_{k-1}F_{n-2} + a_{k-2}F_{n-3} + \cdots + a_1F_{n-k} $

Base case being,

$F_0 = b_0\\F_1 = b_1\\
\cdots\\F_{k-1} = b_{k-1}$

We are to find the generating function of this recurrence relation in terms of the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_j$.

**My attempts:**

From symmetry the solution I get is
$f(x)(1 - a_k - a_{k-1}x - a_{k-2}x^2 \cdots - a_{k-(k-1)}x^{k-1}) = b_0 + (b_0+b_1)x + (b_0+b_1+b_2)x^2 + \cdots + (b_0+b_1+b_2+ \cdots b_{k-1})x^{k-1}$

$\implies f(x)=  \frac {b_0 + (b_0+b_1)x + (b_0+b_1+b_2)x^2 + \cdots + (b_0+b_1+b_2+ \cdots b_{k-1})x^{k-1}}{1-a_k-a_{k-1}x-a_{k-2}x^2- \cdots -a_{k-(k-1)}x^{k-1}} $

where $f(x)$ is the generating function. But I am not sure I can prove it.

Also I would like to express the $t_{th}$ term ie coefficient of $x^t$ in the above. There should be a way to express in $kxk-matrix$ form $M$ such that $M^t[1][1]$ might have the computed coefficients of  $x^t$ .

**PS:**

I have seen many recurrence relation questions across math.stack exchange like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338740/the-generating-function-for-the-fibonacci-numbers) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665961/how-to-use-the-generating-function-fx-x-1-x-x2?noredirect=1&lq=1) or youtube tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp4PWCPzeQs) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXaEnbZkGY0) but no one seems to be making any effort to generate a generalised formula for it.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970860/understanding-a-proof-regarding-the-relationship-between-rational-generating-fun) seems to be the closest where they seem to have done the reverse of my question.

This should be well know as I found there is even a wolframalpha [tool](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/discrete-mathematics/recurrences) doing it

Comment: Suppose $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n F_n.$ Then $(1-\sum_{i=1}^kx^{k-i}a_i)G(x)$ is a polynomial $P(x)$ which is determined by $a_1,...,a_k.$ So $G(x)=\frac {P(x)}{1-\sum_{i=1}^kx^{k-i}a_i}$

Comment: The matrix approach is to let $v_n:=(F_n,F_{n-1}\,ldots,F_{n-k}$ and define $M$ such that $v_{n+1}=Mv_n$. Specifically, the first row of $M$ will be $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ while every other after that will be zero except for those with $M_{k,k+1}=1$. From there one can in principle diagonalize $M$ in order to compute powes of $M$ efficiently.

Comment: @Semiclassical where will the $b_i$'s  fit in that matrix then ? I guess you are talking about a special case where $b_0=1,b_{i>0}=0$ ?

Comment: No. The $b$’s will determine the values of $v_n$ for small $n$. They don’t enter into the matrix $M$.